# How to apply a smooth transition when calling a function that curves a text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, circletype

I have a heading that I curve by calling a function 5s after loading and I am using the CircleType library for that. My only problem is that I cannot apply a smooth transition to the change.

Can someone help me?

Here is the code:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.heading {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  font-size: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  transition: 3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1 class="heading" id="smile">LOVE YOUR SMILE</h1>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/circletype@2.3.0/dist/circletype.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      setTimeout(function () {
        new CircleType(document.getElementById("smile")).dir(-1).radius(700);
      }, 5000);
    </script>
  </body>
```

Thank you!

Comment: This is not possible with that library. It creates separate elements for each letter and then applies a rotation on them. Putting a transition delay on that will give undesired effects.

Comment: Yes, I see that nothing is happening with the transition. What would you suggest?

Comment: You can make the transition visible, but it will not be showing what you want: the letters will not animate along a path that you would expect -- this is because the library sets the transform center and the transform rotation, such that an animation of that change would make the letters fly away and then come closer again to their final position. It is not nice, and there is nothing you can do about that other than use an entirely different solution, not involving that particular library.